# Python unittest using paho-mqtt library does not connect nor publish a message to the mqtt broker

Tags: python, async-await, mqtt, python-unittest, paho

i am trying to generate a unittest in python to test the security of a mqtt broker, but first i just want to create a unittest that uses the paho-mqtt library and actually works. The test should connec to the broker and publish a message, but it doesn't. Btw, i am using visual studio

Here is my code:

```
import unittest
from unittest import IsolatedAsyncioTestCase
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

class Test(IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def  test(self):
        client = mqtt.Client("anonymous_test")
        client.on_connect= on_connect
        client.on_message = on_message
        await client.connect("localhost",1883)
        await client.publish("test",1234)
        print("hello")
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

Here is my mqtt broker's configuration file:

```
allow_anonymous true


listener 8883
protocol mqtt
require_certificate false
#use_identity_as_username true
#password_file C:/Program Files/mosquitto/passwords/passwd_file.txt
#plugin C:/Program Files/mosquitto/mosquitto_dynamic_security.dll
#plugin_opt_config_file C:/Program Files/mosquitto/passwords/dynamic-security.json

#cafile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\mqtt_ca.crt
#certfile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\mqtt_srv.crt
#keyfile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\mqtt_srv.key


socket_domain ipv4
tls_version tlsv1.2


listener 1883
```

I tried to make the test async, but it also doesn't connec nor publish.

Comment: You are not staring the client loop or actually subscribing to any topics